# Cannot add new folder. Upload.aspx gives an 404 error

Tags: document-library, folder, list-form

I am using SharePoint 2010.

I have a library where the folder option is enabled. When I try to add a new folder I get a popup with an 404 error.

When I go to SharePoint Designer and go to the forms folder I see the `upload.aspx` page.

I can check out this document. When I try to edit this page or check it in, it gives me this error:

> The server could not complete your request. For more specific
>   information, click the detail button.

This is the detailed error:

> soap:ServerServer was unable to process request. ---> The file
>   https://portal.myCompany-extra.net/projects/52812898/EXEC/PMF/Forms/Upload.aspx
>   does not exist.

What is wrong with the upload.aspx page? In another library in the same website it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Could be please confirm what really is the issue?

I would like to assume its the error you receive in trying to create a new folder on your document library.

In that case please visit advanced settings->Make New Folder option to yes.

Hope this is what you were looking for !!

Comment: Like I say in my problem description. The folder option is already enabled. Thats not the issue. When I click on the button for a new folder I got a popup with an 404 error.

Comment: @KHA Check whether the list form web part related content is modified by someone else because certainly your able to access Upload.aspx its just when u perceive the data the list form web part responsible fails. Please try restoring to the old version as its a OOB page.

Comment: hi, what do you mean with: list form web part related content?

Comment: @KHA Whatever the New form that shows up uses default list form web part. Since you said its been opened with designer its worth a check to check the content and restore it to the previous version. Could you give it a try and let me know?